# How would I create a directive to apply classes to items in repeat, like odd/even

Tags: angularjs

I realise there is a directive in Angular to apply odd/even classes within an ng-repeat, but I need to add 3 types of class as the image below shows. Not sure how to go about it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scope inside an [`ng-repeat`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) has a couple of extra variables, including $index. You can use that in a way like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="element in collection" ng-class="['left', 'center', 'right'][$index % 3]">{{element.attribute}}</div>
```

`$index` is the index of the element in the array you're iterating over. We're taking the modulo of $index and 3, written as `$index % 3`, whic returns the remaindex of `$index`divided by 3.

Comment: This is the cleanest markup I think, but thanks to everybody that answered :)

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this with `ng-class` directive:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{left: $index%3 === 0, middle: $index%3 === 1, right: $index%3 === 2}"></div>
```

that usage of `ng-class` means: attach `left` class if `$index % 3 === 0` and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Please find the fiddle for the same
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sb_satchitanand/69ATu/)

You can use $index of ng-repeat to set class.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="{left:$index%3==0,middle:$index%3==1,right:$index%3==2}">
```